# Did Fibonacci slow down?

Tags: evaluation

For Fibonacci numbers we have a nice formula:

$$
\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^n-\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^n}{2^{n} \sqrt{5}}
$$

We can implement that in *Mathematica*:

```
a[n_]:= ((1+Sqrt[5])^n-(1-Sqrt[5])^n)/(2^n Sqrt[5])

a[10] //Expand
(* 55 *)
```

We need `Expand` to get rid of all the $\sqrt{5}$'s in the result. For large `n`, expanding gives very large intermediate results and therefore this function becomes very slow.

However, *Mathematica* can do numerical computations to any precision. So we can overcome the problem by computing `a[n]` numerically with a precision at least equal to the number of digits of `a[n]` and then rounding the result. That can be done as follows:

```
b[n_Integer?Positive] := With[{z=((1+Sqrt[5])^n-(1-Sqrt[5])^n)/(2^n*Sqrt[5])},
   Round[N[ z, 1+N[Log[10,z]]]]]

b /@ Range[10]
(* {1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55} *)
```

Now let us compute a very large Fibonacci number by using this function `b` and the built in function `Fibonacci`.

```
n=600000;
r1=b[n]; // RepeatedTiming
r2=Fibonacci[n]; // RepeatedTiming
r1==r2
(*
{0.000068,Null}
{0.0012,Null}
True
*)
```

I am very sure that some years ago the function `b` was slower than the function `Fibonacci`. But now (version 10.4 and 11.0) it is much faster. Has `Fibonacci` indeed slowed down so much or is this a timing problem?

Comment: OTOH, if we go further up (e.g. `n = 6*^6` and `n = 6*^7`), your `b` is only about half as fast as `Fibonacci[]`.

Comment: Funny to see this in the HNQ. I presume he did, he lived to 80 in the middle ages...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There seems to be some significant caching going on for the `b` function.

```
n = 600000;

ClearSystemCache[]
b[n]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.213265, Null} *)

b[n]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000196, Null} *)
```

These timings are in version 11.0.1.  In version 9.0.1 I get 0.29 s for `b[n]`.

I also tried `Do[Fibonacci[n], {1000}] // AbsoluteTiming`, and I got 1.25 s in v11 vs 1.6 s in v9.

Conclusions:

- Later versions of Mathematica seem to be overall faster than older ones.
- `Fibonacci` is in reality much faster than `b`.  The caching effects distort the timing.

A better comparison of the two functions would be to time them with several different `n`:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Table[Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, 600000, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.031772, Null} *)

ClearSystemCache[]
Table[b[n], {n, 1, 600000, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.73996, Null} *)
```

Comment: So I was strongly mislead by the RepeatedTiming. Many thanks for pointing that out.